# withColumn not allowing me to use max() function to generate a new column

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataset like this:

```
a = sc.parallelize([[1,2,3],[0,2,1],[9,8,7]]).toDF(["one", "two", "three"])
```

I want to have a dataset that adds a new column that is equal to the largest value in the other three columns.
The output would look like this:

```
+----+----+-----+-------+
|one |two |three|max_col|
+----+----+-----+-------+
|   1|   2|    3|      3|
|   0|   2|    1|      2|
|   9|   8|    7|      9|
+----+----+-----+-------+
```

I thought I would use `withColumn`, like so:

```
b = a.withColumn("max_col", max(a["one"], a["two"], a["three"]))
```

but this yields the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/spark152/python/pyspark/sql/column.py", line 418, in __nonzero__
    raise ValueError("Cannot convert column into bool: please use '&' for 'and', '|' for 'or', "
ValueError: Cannot convert column into bool: please use '&' for 'and', '|' for 'or', '~' for 'not' when building DataFrame boolean expressions.
```

Odd. Does `max` return a `bool`? Not according to [the documentation on `max`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max). Okay. Weird.

I find it odd that this works:

```
b = a.withColumn("max_col", a["one"] + a["two"] + a["three"]))
```

And the fact that it works makes me think even more strongly that `max` is behaving some way I don't understand.

I also tried `b = a.withColumn("max_col", max([a["one"], a["two"], a["three"]]))`, which passes in the three columns as a list rather than 3 separte elements. This yields the same error as above.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Actually what you need here is `greatest` not `max`:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import greatest

a.withColumn("max_col", greatest(a["one"], a["two"], a["three"]))
```

And just for completeness you can use `least` to find the minimum:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import least

a.withColumn("min_col", least(a["one"], a["two"], a["three"]))
```

Regarding the error you see it is quite simple. `max` depends on the rich comparisons. When you compare two columns you get a `Column`:

```
type(col("a") < col("b")
## pyspark.sql.column.Column
```

PySpark explicitly forbids converting columns to booleans (you can check `Column.__nonzero__` source) because it is simply meaningless. It is only a logical expression which cannot be evaluated in the driver context.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it right, you mismatch max of a column and max of a row. In fact .withColumn needs to receive a column, what you need is a row operation.

```
b=a.map(lambda row: (row.one, row.two, row.three, max(row)))
```

b is then a rdd, you can convert it to dataframe

```
b.toDF('one','two','three','max')
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `max` from python as it doesn't return the expected `pyspark.sql.Column`. An example of pyspark DataFrame functions is `array` which builds a list from a few columns, note the return:

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/functions.html#array

To achieve what you need, you could write a user-defined-function like (UNTESTED)

```
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

def my_max(*cols):
    return max(cols)

udf_my_max = udf(my_max, IntegerType)

df.withColumn('max_col', udf_my_max(a.columns))
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work for me. Sure it's a small issue / bug since you didn't get a chance to test. I would prefer to stay using DataFrames rather than RDDs, so if you find a working solution I would appreciate it!