# how to get maximum date from a row in pyspark

Tags: pyspark

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
maxcol = func.udf(lambda row: F.max(row))
temp = [(("ID1", '2019-01-01', '2019-02-01')), (("ID2", '2018-01-01', '2019-05-01')), (("ID3", '2019-06-01', '2019-04-01'))]
t1 = spark.createDataFrame(temp, ["ID", "colA", "colB"])
maxDF = t1.withColumn("maxval", maxcol(F.struct([t1[x] for x in t1.columns[1:]])))
```

All I want is a new column with maximum date from colA and ColB. I am running the same code and when I am doing maxDF.show then I am getting below error :

```
 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_jvm'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to calculate max value in some columns per row in pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44833836/how-to-calculate-max-value-in-some-columns-per-row-in-pyspark)

Comment: You don't need a `udf` for this. Use [`pyspark.sql.functions.greatest`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.greatest). In your case, you're probably looking for `maxDF = t1.withColumn("maxval", F.greatest(*t1.columns[1:]))`

Comment: Your code doesn't work because you're using `pyspark.sql.functions.max` when you should be using `__builtin__.max`

Answer (score 0):

[similar to this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37838361/withcolumn-not-allowing-me-to-use-max-function-to-generate-a-new-column)

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import column

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Python Spark").getOrCreate()

temp = [("ID1", '2019-01-01', '2019-02-01'), ("ID2", '2018-01-01', '2019-05-01'),
        ("ID3", '2019-06-01', '2019-04-01')]

t1 = spark.createDataFrame(temp, ["ID", "colA", "colB"])

maxDF = t1.withColumn("maxval", F.greatest(t1["colA"], t1["colB"]))
maxDF.show()
```

**output**

```
| ID|      colA|      colB|    maxval|
+---+----------+----------+----------+
|ID1|2019-01-01|2019-02-01|2019-02-01|
|ID2|2018-01-01|2019-05-01|2019-05-01|
|ID3|2019-06-01|2019-04-01|2019-06-01|
+---+----------+----------+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try something like this...  use [to_date()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.to_date) to convert to Date objects first, then compare:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

temp = [(("ID1", '2019-01-01', '2019-02-01')), (("ID2", '2018-01-01', '2019-05-01')), (("ID3", '2019-06-01', '2019-04-01'))]
t1 = spark.createDataFrame(temp, ["ID", "colA", "colB"])
t2 = t1.select("ID", to_date(t1.colA).alias('colADate'), to_date(t1.colB).alias('colBDate'))
t3 = t2.withColumn('maxDateFromRow', when(t2.colADate > t2.colBDate, t2.colADate).otherwise(t2.colBDate))

t3.show()
```

Which returns:

```
+---+----------+----------+--------------+
| ID|  colADate|  colBDate|maxDateFromRow|
+---+----------+----------+--------------+
|ID1|2019-01-01|2019-02-01|    2019-02-01|
|ID2|2018-01-01|2019-05-01|    2019-05-01|
|ID3|2019-06-01|2019-04-01|    2019-06-01|
+---+----------+----------+--------------+
```

Comment: [Do not do `from pyspark.sql.functions import *`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55711135/5858851).